# how can i include the DLL in the VS 2013 ultimate?

Tags: c#

how to create a file. exe in VS 2013 ultimate and add the layers in the project executable

My solution is called "control" within the solution and have 4 projects "AcessoBancoDados", "Business", "transfer", "telaAcesso"

if I select the project access screen and go on projects / properties / tab publish the VS will generate an exe file., but only screen access, and other projects as part of the solution, how to add, because if I run the file . exe on my pc just fine, but if I run the file in another pc it will not find the dll file, because in my view the only VS generated. exe file of a project and not the entire solution.

or is there another way to generate an executable in VS.
thanks

Comment: Is this a Click Once or a Web app? Or just a normal application? And is the DLL you mention a class library, or is it an unmanaged code DLL (e.g. an unmanaged C/C++ DLL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get WIX - WIndows Installer for XML, made by microsoft but open source and the mental successor and adult brother of the kind of not too smart setup projects that existed pre VS 1013.

Read the documentation, learn it, make a setup, finished.

Comment: hi tom tom, but i only want add a DLL, in others versions, the DLL's are create automatic, in the VS 2013 i don't know where is.

Comment: Same place like before. Seriously. Nothing has changed there.